# PubNub Subscribe Keeps Unsubscribing

Tags: javascript, node.js, pubnub

I am using the PubNub Node.js module to listen to a channel but it randomly unsubscribes and I would like it to auto-reconnect if this happens.

I have added the `restore: true` option but this does not seem to be working.

```
const pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: config.SUB_KEY,
  uuid: config.UUID,
  restore: true,
  autoNetworkDetection: true,
});
```

Comment: `restore` only acts to reconnect/resubscribe when/if a dropped network connection is reestablished by the process and this is only effective within the context of a browser AFAIK.

Comment: The real question is what is happening to cause the disconnect. How long before the connection is dropped? Does it happen at a consistent interval (like 4 minutes or 1 minute, etc)? Which version of the PubNub Node SDK are you using? Can you run your process with [PubNub Node SDK logging enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide),capture this scenario and share the log file (redact any PubNub keys before posting here or send to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and include a link to this SO post).

Comment: @CraigConover I am not sure what is causing the disconnects, they seem random between 1-6 hours. I will enable logging and see what I can find

Comment: @CraigConover This may be a facepalm moment. Although your suggestion did help me discover that it was no PubNub that was disconnecting. The purpose of my code is to listen to the PubNub channel and then broadcast onto Twitch. It looks like it was actually Twitch that was disconnecting. I will let you know in a few hours if I fixed it.

Comment: Ah, cool. I think I have a better solution for you. See my Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Functions instead of Server-side Subscribe

### Server-side Subscribe challenges to consider

Subscribing on the server requires your server to keep an open connection to PubNub at all times. For a single channel or several channels, this is not difficult. But scale that to thousands of channels and you are putting quite a bit of responsibility on your server and you to implement this in a scalable and resident way.

- What if the server goes down, is there another instance to listen to those channels?
- How many channels/message (rate of messages) can your server handle before you need more instances to handle the load?
- If you have multiple instance subscribing to the same channels, how do you determine which server handles each message (prevent duplicate handling)?
- How do you determine which channels each server listens to if no duplicate those channels across all instances?

PubNub will scale, but will your server/s? And there are answers to all of the above using best practices (contact PubNub support if you are in need of this sort of design) but there is another way that requires less work on your part and puts the burden on PubNub, which is why we exist, [using PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/events/functions/overview).

### PubNub Functions FTW!

So, you want your server to receive messages that are published to a channel (or many channels)? Create an ***After Publish Function*** that binds to the channel you were originally subscribing to, and send the message to your server [using `xhr`](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/functions/xhr-module) to `POST` the message. You will need to provide a REST endpoint on your server to receive these web requests but that is going to be the code you have in place to receive the `subscribe` messages. You just need to add that code to your REST endpoint (assuming you know how to implement this endpoint but if not, there are plenty of tuts about that).

If you want to modify the message before it is sent to your server, use a ***Before Publish Function***.

To get a jumpstart on the Functions code for third party features, you can look at [PubNub Integrations](https://www.pubnub.com/integrations/). But the code you need to get you started is a simple `xhr`.

Comment: Do let me know if you require further details on this.

Comment: This is an interesting concept and definitely a better option. Although I only have access to the subscribe functionality currently. But I will contact the developers of the site to see if I can utilise this functionality.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. I want to discuss strategies with the PubNub Solution Architect team about how best for PubNub key owners to expose Function calls to thirds parties in a secure way.